# Adding rule for Azure Storage Lifecycle Management via REST API does not persist (no errors thrown on request) - using StorageV2

Tags: azure-storage

I'm trying to add a simple rule via REST API but it does not persist. Response = OK, and no errors thrown. I can create the same rule via powershell and it works.

After submitting my JSON, I receive HttpStatus "OK" and get a response payload back, but the rule is not saved and shown in the Azure Portal.

I call this URL / PUT:
[https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}/blobServices/default?api-version=2019-06-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/%7BsubscriptionId%7D/resourceGroups/%7BresourceGroupName%7D/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/%7BaccountName%7D/blobServices/default?api-version=2019-06-01)

Request body:

```
{
    "properties": {
        "policy": {
            "rules": [
                {
                    "enabled": true,
                    "name": "myRule",
                    "type": "Lifecycle",
                    "definition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "baseBlob": {
                                "delete": {
                                    "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 10
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "filters": {
                        "blobTypes": [
                            "blockBlob"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

HttpStatus = OK
Response body:

```
{
    "id": "/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}/blobServices/default",
    "name": "default",
    "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/blobServices",
    "properties": {}
}
```

Any ideas why this is not working, any updates API versions which I haven't found yet???

Comment: COuld you please tell me if you can create policy via Azure portal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to  the response body you provide, you made an error. The `filters` should be a property in `definition`. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/managementpolicies/createorupdate).

For example

```
{
    "properties": {
        "policy": {
            "rules": [{
                    "enabled": true,
                    "name": "deleteBlock",
                    "type": "Lifecycle",
                    "definition": {
                        "actions": {
                            "baseBlob": {
                                "delete": {
                                    "daysAfterModificationGreaterThan": 180
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "filters": {
                            "blobTypes": [
                                "blockBlob"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

**Besides, please note that The lifecycle management feature is available in all Azure regions for General Purpose v2 (GPv2) accounts, blob storage accounts, Premium Block Blob storage accounts**. For more details, please refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-lifecycle-management-concepts?tabs=azure-portal)

Comment: You are so right, thank you for helping...

I put the wrong URL in my post, I'm using this one (if anyone hits this thread):

https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}/managementPolicies/default?api-version=2019-06-01

and it works after your small tip :-)